How to Parse Complex SQL Values String into Columns Safely
I'm working with a string that represents SQL parameter values and need to parse it into individual columns. Here's an example of such a string:
values = "( 14587, '290\'960', 'This is, a, difficult,,, string that uses '' \" and even '' \" , '' '', ''. So it definitely needs to be checked for escape characters.', null )"


The goal is to extract these values into a list of columns, handling various challenges:

Different Data Types: The values could be integers, strings, or null.

Escape Characters: Strings may contain escaped single quotes (''),
backslashes, or other special characters.

Embedded Delimiters: Commas
may appear inside strings, making naive splitting by commas
impossible.

Quotes Matching: Properly matching single quotes around
strings is essential.


I attempted to use a regular expression to handle splitting by commas outside of quotes:
import re

values = "( 14587, '290\'960', 'This is, a, difficult,,, string that uses '' \" and even '' \" , '' '', ''. So it definitely needs to be checked for escape characters.', null )"

# Remove outer parentheses and leading/trailing spaces
cleaned_values = values.strip().strip('()')

# Use regular expression to split by commas outside quotes, accounting for escaped quotes
values_list = re.split(r",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)", cleaned_values)

# Strip whitespace from each part
values_list = [v.strip() for v in values_list]

print(cleaned_values)
for value in values_list:
    print(value)

This approach works to some extent but feels fragile and may not handle all edge cases, especially more complex SQL strings.
Question:
What is the best and most reliable way to parse such SQL VALUES strings into individual columns, ensuring the following:

Properly handling different data types.
Escaping and parsing special characters correctly.
Preserving the integrity of strings with embedded commas or quotes.

Would a dedicated SQL parser or another method be more suitable than regular expressions?

It's unclear to me what your use case is, but I'd either: 1. defer the parsing to the SQL server itself (this might include possible SQL injections, of course) or 2. use a proper SQL parser (now you have to figure out how to reject values that would cause an SQL injection). Using regexes for this is very error-prone, unless you can clearly specify (and trust) your input, but that doesn't seem to be the case from what you're describing.

The second term in value is not valid SQL as the slash in \' is evaluated by Python and effectively disappears so you are left with a term containing an unbalanced number of single quotes.

You can search for:

Either the start of the string with an opening brace or a term delimiter and then optional spaces before the term (?:^\(|,)\s*;
The term which is either:

A string without quotes or whitespace [^'\s]+; or
A string starting and ending with single quotes containing zero-or-more characters that are either non-single quotes or an escaped single quote (either with a slash or by two single quotes) '(?:[^'\\]|['\\]')*'


Followed by optional spaces and either the term delimiter or the end of the string \s*(?=,|\)$).

Like this:
import re

values = r"""( 14587, '290\'960', 'This is, a, difficult,,, string that uses '' " and even '' " , '' '', ''. So it definitely needs to be checked for escape characters.', null )"""

values_list = re.findall(
    r"(?:^\(|,)\s*([^'\s,]+|'(?:[^'\\]|['\\]')*')\s*(?=,|\)$)",
    values.strip(),
)

for value in values_list:
    print(value)

Which outputs:
14587
'290\'960'
'This is, a, difficult,,, string that uses '' " and even '' " , '' '', ''. So it definitely needs to be checked for escape characters.'
null

